# How to use functions in mixin params (sass/scss)

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

Here's a problem:

I have some mixin in sass/scss:

```
@function strip-unit($value) {
  @return $value / ($value * 0 + 1);
}

@mixin fluid-type($min-vw, $max-vw, $min-font-size, $max-font-size) {
  $u1: unit($min-vw);
  $u2: unit($max-vw);
  $u3: unit($min-font-size);
  $u4: unit($max-font-size);

  @if $u1 == $u2 and $u1 == $u3 and $u1 == $u4 {
    & {
      font-size: $min-font-size;
      @media screen and (min-width: $min-vw) {
        font-size: calc(#{$min-font-size} + #{strip-unit($max-font-size - $min-font-size)} * ((100vw - #{$min-vw}) / #{strip-unit($max-vw - $min-vw)}));
      }
      @media screen and (min-width: $max-vw) {
        font-size: $max-font-size;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I took it from there: [Fluid Typography](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/)

Everything works perfectly fine, when I use the mixin in "normal way":

```
@include fluid-type(20rem, 90rem, 2rem, 10rem);
@include fluid-type(400px, 1600px, 24px, 96px);
```

But, what if I have some function converting px to rem units:

```
@function rem($px) {
    @return ($px / 16) + rem;
}
```

And I want that function to help me with that:

```
@include fluid-type( rem(400), rem(1600), rem(24), rem(96) );
```

At this moment I catch an error :/

Can I do something about this? I don't wanna to covert px to rem manually every time I have to use the mixin.

Comment: You would do it the same way that `strip-unit` works. You put the function inside your mixin and convert the values there.

Comment: @dinisfor Tnx for the answer I tried. I can't figure how to do that...